# Crashlytics(Android) clear log before next crash

Tags: android, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I have a situation where I want to add some logs to Crashlystic for Android, but not always send it. Then before coming back to the same function I want to clear the log. For this I can't seem to find how to do this. Below is an illustration of the situation:

```
public foo() {

    bar();
    bar();
    bar();

}

public bar() {
    // Clear log here, but I don't know how
    ...

    // Add new log here.
    Crashlytics.log(1, "TAG", "log information");
    Crashlytics.log(1, "TAG", "log information");
    Crashlytics.log(1, "TAG", "log information");

    if (condition) {
        Crashlytics.logException(new Exception("Throwing the actual non fatal error to log"));
    }
}
```

The problem is that when not clearing the log, the next actual non-fatal crash will have all the logging for all the times it was not intended to be send. I will need just the logs of the last time `bar()` was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

With Crashlytics' logs that functionality isn't an option. You can use  [custom keys] (https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html#custom-keys) and then you can set the value to nil or empty to reset the value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Personally I'd like to see a functionality like this, but I think I can manage the same result using custom keys.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, much appreciated!

Comment: Hey! In Java, we can set `String` to null but we cannot set `int` to null. How can we reset `int` `float` `long` `double` to null. How to reset these keys?